# Save points in Borderlands Claptrap DLC

Tags: borderlands, borderlands-claptraps-revolution

I've been eyeing the new Borderlands DLC (Claptrap's Robot Revolution), but there's one thing I'd like to know before picking it up: Does it continue the insane trend of the other DLC of putting you back at the starting point every single time you exit the game and come back?

If so it's a no-sale for me, since it ended up taking me something like 15 hours to get through the General Knoxx DLC as a direct result of this design flaw. I can typically only play for 30 minutes or so at a time, and I don't want to spend 20 of that driving back to where I was last time I left off.

If there's some reasonably dispersed respawn points throughout, however, I'll gladly play! I like the game, I just don't have time to waste on a design that artificially inflates game time by forcing me through the same areas over and over again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The game starts of in Tartarus Station, and when you quit/save the game anywhere in the DLC, it sends you back to the beginning.

Just a side note: I just beat the DLC and this is by far the most boring of the DLC available (I own them all), but that is just my opinion. I would explain but I don't want to spoil it for people who don't want to know.

Comment: Well, that answers it then. If I can't pick up where I leave off (within reason) then I have no interest in the DLC. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: The claptrap DLC is no where near as bad as General Knoxx in terms of traveling. While you do start back at the "beginning", it takes less than half the time to get where you are going. I too LOATH all the driving in General Knoxx, but it did not bother me at all in the clap trap DLC.